# How to get the return value of an event handler?

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events

I would like to return from the function of an event some value.

Below, you can find html and js where I've put a button. I would like to have an output true or false. I have only information about event type in the console but I do not know how to put true or false value outside the function to a variable (or to another function - I would like to make of this information as a parameter in a different place).

```
    <body class="container">
     <button class="button">Click me</button>

     <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        function clickFunct(e){
            if(e.target.classList.contains("button")){
                console.log(e.type);
                return true
            }
            else{
                console.log("to nie przycisk")
                return false
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("click", clickFunct);
        })
    });
```

I've removed "my tries" from code to have transparent code.

Comment: You'll have to put a call to the function inside the "click" handler. It doesn't make sense to `return` a value in the sense you described.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep things separated:

1. The event handler should do its own thing. Optionally it can return a value
2. If you need to capture that return value, wrap your event handler in a function that will capture that return value and give it to another function

We can create a `notify` function which takes a function `fn` and the handler itself `handler`. It returns another event handler that call the original handler and pass its return value to the function.

```js
const notify = (fn, handler) => e => {
  fn(handler(e));
};
```

This way you can reuse it with any event handlers:

```js
const notify = (fn, handler) => e => {
  fn(handler(e));
};

const logEvent = x => {
  alert(`event handler has returned "${x}"`)
};

const make_red = e => {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  return 42;
};

const make_green = e => {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  return 84;
};

document.querySelector('#id1').addEventListener('click', notify(logEvent, make_red));
document.querySelector('#id2').addEventListener('click', notify(logEvent, make_green));
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">Click to make it red</div>
<div id="id2">Click to make it green</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in another function and assign the value returned to a variable outside.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  function clickFunct(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("button")) {
      console.log(e.type);
      return true
    }
    else {
      console.log("to nie przycisk")
      return false
    }
  }

  let returnedByClickHandler;
  document.addEventListener("click", event => {
    returnedByClickHandler = clickFunct(event);
  });
});
```

Or pass it to a function which will get called with the value on occurence of the event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  function callback(value) {
    // do something
  }

  function clickFunct(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("button")) {
      console.log(e.type);
      callback(true)
    }
    else {
      console.log("to nie przycisk")
      callback(false)
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", clickFunct);
});
```